# Problem on IE6-8 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm stuck here with this IE6 issue.. always a pain. So I'm using jQuery's "live" feature to add a product each time. Then once each dropdown's value is changed, an input field assigned to it changes its value too so when I hit submit, it sends all the info.

Everything works perfectly fine except in IE6, IE7, and IE8. I have no idea why... I've gone through the code and everything... so please guys. Help! :) These are all the files:

Index.php

```
http://pastie.org/967139
```

Submit.php

```
http://pastie.org/967140
```

JS

```
http://pastie.org/967141
```

Please guys, I'm really stuck here. I would appreciate some help.

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 0):

Your using a live event for the form submission. Not sure that ie plays nice with this.

I am not sure what purpose using live here serves here anyway since you do not appear to be dynamically adding the form to the dom.

Try changing

`$('form#send-it').live('submit', function() {`

to

```
$('#send-it').submit( function() {
```